# From Database to JS to Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vue.js

Is it advisable passing some nonsensitive data to vue within an inline script?

HTML

```
<script>
    var foo = <?php echo $foo ?>
</script>
```

Vue.js

```
new Vue({
    data: { 
        foo: foo 
    }
});
```

Comment: Yea this is fine, you could even just put the php echo directly in the Vue data. Make sure your variable isn't a common name though, global namespace and all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bit opinionated, but I'd avoid using a global variable like that in an application. Instead, I'd make use of HTML5 `data-` attributes and store useful bits of data the frontend needs in them.

You can do something like this:

```
<body data-my-thing='{"foo": "bar", "baz": true}'>
```

The above example uses JSON, what I'd normally do is use `json_encode` in a controller or view composer and just echo out the string like so (since we're using Balde here, the JSON is automatically escaped):

```
<body data-my-thing='{{ $myJson }}'>
```

If you were just using plain PHP then you should escape the JSON like this:

```
<body data-my-thing='<?=htmlspecialchars($myJson) ?>'>
```

Of course, you don't need to JSON, if it's more appropriate you can just store a plain string or number in there. It depends on the needs of your application.

To grab the value from your data attribute you'd just use the following JavaScript:

```
document.body.getAttribute('data-my-thing');
```

And if you've made use of JSON, don't forget to decode it!

```
JSON.parse(document.body.getAttribute('data-my-thing'));
```

Comment: You'll probably want to `htmlspecialchars()` JSON used in this manner.

Comment: There's no need to use htmlspecialchars in a Blade template - everything is automatically escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `data-` attributes to bootstrap data, but I kept running into issues involving quotes.

Say that this:

`<body data-my-thing='{{ $myJson }}'>`

Evaluates to this:

`<body data-my-thing='{"foo": "bar", "baz": true}'>`

No big deal. What if your data looks like this?

`<body data-my-thing='{"foo": "bar's", "baz": true}'>`

Suddenly you have an issue. That's why I've used the script solution that the original poster mentioned above.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is made for solving that.

Comment: Would you mind posting a solution that used that? I'm not from the PHP world so my experience is more general. (Though the issue I mentioned above did bite me in production.)